# ReactJS - assets folder not loading for particular Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React Application, I have certain images and logos inside public -> assets folder.

I have several Routes in the application and whenever I inspect sources in the Chrome developer tools, I see the assets folder does not load/appear for certain Routes.

E.g.

1. Route 1:
   Route exact path="/myApp/sign-out" component={SignOut} -
   for routes having only two slashes, the assets folder and my logos load.
2. Route 2:

Route exact path="/myApp/home/accounts" component={Accounts} -

for routes having more than two slashes (if you observe the route
closely) - the assets folder does not load.

I have spent some time on this issue - The route difference may not even be the cause, but this is what I have observed.

Edit:
This is not an import issue / or a import path issue. I have verified the paths.

Moreover - the assets folder itself does not load under certain Routes (Observed under sources tab in the chrome dev tools). That is the main issue

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check out the import path in files inside other folder

Comment: Yeah I have. There is one Private Route component. I see assests and images loading on the Private Route component for one route - but not for the other Route.

Answer (score 1):

It is a path issue. If you’re putting them in public, the URL will be different depending on the route path.